# zk framework memory grid

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, zk, java-ee-5

I use zk framework `MVVM` approach and want display `grid` with 1000-2000 rows per page.(It is really need for user) But it is a lot of information and every user will consume about 30Mb if i will save my `grid` `model` (`List<Object>`) in memory on server side. I decide what will be good just render this sort of information and clean memory on server side, but if i use this approach i should go to client side programming. (write js for ajax calls and etc.) 
Can't find good solution for this issue. What i should use `auRequest`, `RowRender` or `Render script` on client side or just null data after render grid?

**UPD:** ZUL

```
<grid apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
      viewModel="@id('vm') @init('Pojo')"
      self="@define(content)" height="100%" width="100%">
      model="@load(vm.o)" emptyMessage="${c:l('empty_table')}"
      stubonly="true" onCreate="@command('clear')">
   <columns>
      ...cols...
   </columns>
   <template name="model">
      <row>
           <label value="@load(each.data)" />
      </row>
   </template>
</grid>
```

JAVA:

```
 public class Pojo {

     private List<Object> o;
     private Grid g;

     @Init
     public void init(){
        o = loadFromDaoOneHundredItems()
     }

     @AfterCompose
     public afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view){
          g.setPageSize(1000);
     }
 }
```

**UPD**

```
    final Rows rs = new Rows();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        final Row r = new Row();
        r.appendChild(new Label("sdf"));
        r.appendChild(new Label("sdf"));
        r.appendChild(new Label("sdf"));
        rs.appendChild(r);
    }
    grid.appendChild(rs);
    ListModelList<Object> o = null;
    grid.setModel(o);
```

Comment: First Please provide code. Second, how can 2000 rows be displayed at the same time? Do you use ZK CE or PE/EE? What kind of data are those? Do different users need to load different data? If not, you should cache your data (same if only small differences must be saved individually).

Comment: i add pseudo code, yes 2000 rows it is terrible but can. I use free version of ZK. I think is CE. Data POjO `String` and `int`. Yes each user need load different data. I want just output `html` like in `php`. And via JS send AJAX or via auRequests. But i can't find tutorials. Official zk cut to pieces. Hard to understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZK provides many ways to handle your logic client side.
At first you should read the [communication part of the client-side zk manual](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Client-side%20Reference/Communication).
In addition, [this awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438088/1787809) should be helpful.

You should know, that `model="@load(vm.o)"` calls `Grid.setModel(...)`
and saves a reference so that data will not be deleted by javas gc.

So I think the only way to solve this, by still using MVVM even if it
breaks the pettern as far as I understand MVVM, would be to call

```
onCreate="@command('createRows',grid=self)"
```

and add a method like

```
@Command("createRows")
public void createRows(@BindingParam("grid") Grid grid){
 //add rows manually here
}
```

But I have to say that for your task, I would prefer to use ZK MVC,
cos of better readability/maintainability and more control cos of java.

Comment: After i use `setModel(null)` it erase all rows from grid. I just really no need `2Mb` on server for 25 `Row` instances. And Pojo classes in model good to be null too after render.

Comment: I updated what i did by your advice, but is still in memory. I see in YourKit. Row and Rows and Labels. Root GC ref to DesktopImpl-->CacheMap of zk. Can you explain how it would be in MVC approach? I ask it because i think what whatever approach do you use. Core is still same.

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem. So what is possible is, to remove your (I assume loaded from a DB) data structure by locally load it in `createRows` without use of `setModel(..)`. But, if you want a serverside grid without `Rows` and `Row` instances attached to it, you need [stubonly](http://tiny.cc/zkstubonly) which is ZK EE only. Alternatively you could implement the stubonly functionality your self, but I have no experience with this.